# How can I get multiple Eloquent relationships?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am having trouble trying to set up a relationship between tables.

```
- courses
    |- id
    |- title
- sessions
    |- id
    |- course_id
    |- title
- users
    |-id
    |- name
- user_roles
    |- user_id
    |- course_id
```

I am able to show all sessions for a given course and all users who are registered for a given session. I would also like to show the users role. Since I could have any number of sessions for any given course, my pivot table only has `course_id` and the `user_id` columns.

When I visit a url like this: `mysite.com/sessions/1` I want to show the current users for the session. It would look something like this:

```
"My Course"
    "Session One"
        "John Doe"
            "Admin"
        "Jane Doe"
            "Editor"
            "Contributor"
        "Name"
           "Foo"
```

Coming from CodeIgniter, I'd just pass in the course id and user id to find the corresponding roles. Here is what I have that is 90% working.

**Course.php**

```
public function sessions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Session::class);
}
```

**Session.php**

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
}
```

**Role.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_roles');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample relationship,

**Courses.php**

```
//means course has many sessions
public function sessions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sessions','course_id', 'id');
}

//course user
public function course_user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'course_id');
}
```

**Sessions.php**

```
//means Session belongs to course
public function sessions(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course','course_id', 'id');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function sessions(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course','course_id', 'id');
}
//user courses
public function user_course(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_roles','courses_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Note: if you want user role management system, then its better to install and configure the Zizaco Entrust package, its much better instead doing it manually. [Entrust Package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)